# HTTP Redirect form external_api?

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

I've got an `external_api` implemented that I can currently hit the standard way;

```
http://localhost/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=foo&wsfunction=local_test_function&moodlewsrestformat=json
```

and it returns:

```
https://google.com/?q=test
```

The thing I can not figure out is, how can I make this return an HTTP/302? I'm trying to work around the fact that atto won't run JS code, and I thought I could just do an iFrame that has it's src set to my webservice, but all I can seem to do is return a string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, Moodle web service API is very much designed around a typical RPC API. You make a call, and you get an answer. There aren't any implementation of HTTP verbs, nor respond codes apart from 500, and 403, when an exception is raised, or permissions are lacking.

I'm actually uncertain why you would want to do this anyway. The `external_api` is meant to interact with Moodle, not to redirect elsewhere, especially if you end-up passing a user's token to an iframe.